# How do I report a problem with the Ubuntu Guide website?

Tags: community

How do I report a problem with the Ubuntu Guide website?

http://ubuntuguide.org/images/UbuntuGuideSaucyPt1.epub is linked from http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Saucy_Repositories under 'eBook Version' above the list of contents at top of page,. However, that link is 404'd. Also tried http://ubuntuguide.org/images/UbuntuGuideSaucy.epub which also fails.

So, where do we report Fail at ubuntuguide.org? I see nowhere there to so do.

I have also tried, twice on separate days, to register there, but never get the confirmation email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you report it to the project itself by contacting its maintainers directly.

For example:

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/User:Perspectoff#Contact

...and

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/User:Krampo

It looks like ubuntuguide.org is an independent project, created and maintained by a few volunteers. Although it's a collaborative wiki, I don't think everyone can or is meant to register (not sure why they have the button).

Comment: Krampo advised I report it to the maintainer, Perspectoff, which has been done. TY for digging further, for some reason I did not/could not find that.

Comment: Turns out registration there does not result in a verification email, despite what it tells you.